# How can I select and unselect check boxes in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

My code only doing if chckAll.Checked than make all the check boxes selected... What I want to achieve is when any of the check boxes unselected, after selecting all the check boxes make the chckAll unselected.... Also If all the check boxes selected by one by than make the  chckAll selected...How can I do that?

```
private void chckAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chckAll.Checked)
            {
                foreach (Control ctrl in checkBoxesPanel3.Controls)
                {
                    CheckBox chkboxes = ctrl as CheckBox;
                    if (chkboxes != null)
                    {
                        chkboxes.Checked = true;

                    }

                }

            }           

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add below event to all other checkboxes except chckAll

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckFlg = true;
    if (!CheckAllFlg)
    {
        chckAll.Checked = checkBoxesPanel3.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Name != "chckAll").All(c => c.Checked);  
    }
    CheckFlg = false;
}

private void chckAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckAllFlg = true;

    if (!CheckFlg)
    {
        foreach (CheckBox ctrl in checkBoxesPanel3.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Name != "chckAll"))
        {
            ctrl.Checked = chckAll.Checked;
        }
    }
    CheckAllFlg = false;
}
```

You need to define two property  as below

```
public partial class Form1
{
    public bool CheckAllFlg { get; set; }
    public bool CheckFlg { get; set; }
```

Comment: Also If all the check boxes selected by one by than make the chckAll selected...How can I do that?

Comment: For example, I have 5 check boxes and one chckAll check box.... with your code If any check boxes unselected than it makes chckAll check box unselected...But what if I select all five check boxes one bye one? and when I completed checking except chckAll I want to aoutomatically select chckAll box too...

Comment: is your `chckAll` check box also in `checkBoxesPanel3`?

Comment: Yes it is also inside my checkBoxesPanel3

Comment: Ok then, as my updated code you can give the name of `chckAll` check box as you given and it will work

Comment: Now, When I select any of the check box it makes all the check boxes selected?

Comment: after selecting fifth check box.. . code automatically select the chckAll. Because, logically all the check boxes selected...